# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import - Express

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I have this in my index.js

```
import express from 'express'
import data from './data/data'


const app = express();
const PORT = 3000; 

app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Your server is running on ${PORT}`)
);
```

This is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "express-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "backend provisioning",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js"
    },
    "author": "B",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.16.3"
    }
}
```

When I run nodemon , I got

```
[nodemon] 1.17.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
/Users/b/Desktop/express-app/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import express from 'express'
                                                            ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Did I forget to do anything to be able to use the import command?

I did this :

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-preset-stage-0
npm install express
nodemon
```

same result

I also try this

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
nodemon
```

same result

---

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets":[
        "env",
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think you need to install babel-core also.

Comment: You need to run `npm start`, not `nodemon`. Notice you pass extra parameters to nodemon in your `start` script

Comment: I ran into the same issue the other day. I tried to use import in my express server and ran nodemon to watch the file even though I installed all the necessary dependencies, core, env, stage-0 etc... does nodemon not support import??

Comment: @Iso, you're correct !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NodeJS supports `import` natively only [experimentally](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules), and only if your script has the .mjs extension.

That's why the `start` in your package.json is referring to [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node), which transpiles ES6 code into classic JS on-the-fly before running it. But I doubt even that command will work, because you're not passing any presets to babel to run the script. Try this command:

`nodemon --exec babel-node --presets env index.js`

[OR]

Rename your file to have .mjs extension, then run this:

`nodemon --experimental-modules index.mjs`

Comment: I tried your first option, I got the same result, when running nodemon.

Comment: My node version is `v8.9.4`

Comment: @ihue I just tried your exact script on 8.9.4 in my box, and it works for me. Are you sure you executed my command exactly as provided? And are you getting exactly the same error as in your question?

Comment: I suppose to do `npm start` not `nodemon`

Comment: @ihue Ok, so you changed your package.json to use my command then?

Comment: @ihue I corrected my answer, it looks like experimental support is available in version 8 as well. So you might want to try my second option if the first is still not working (I checked again and both options do work on 8.9.4)

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you have lower version of node. please upgrade it to at least v10.0

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give a overview who came to this situation, becouse its very painfull.
Firstly in ES6 there is no support for **import Express** or **require express** together and inspite of this we can implement it with **esm** or **dynamic-babel**

What is reason, James explained in here [Update on ES6](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c)

and the reason [Node.js, TC-39, and Modules](https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e)

In my case i have using import and require in the same project and also i need to debugging and hot-reloading features, i have assaulted with this error and figureout a way. 
first i decide to use nodemon to debugging and hot reloading in my **package.json**
like below:

```
"debug-api": "nodemon --inspect -r esm src/api/server/index.js",
"debug-store": "nodemon --inspect -r esm dist/store/server/index.js",
"debug": "concurrently npm:debug-*" // if you add --source-maps to here it will make HMR
```

i have deleted .babelrc file and i have defined loaders on just one place in the webpack like below

```
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/react", ["@babel/preset-env", {
                        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                        "shippedProposals": true,
                        "debug": true,
                        "include": ["es7.promise.finally", "es7.symbol.async-iterator", "es6.array.sort"],
                        "modules": false,     
                      }]
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        ["@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator", {
                            "asyncGenerators": true,
                            "generators": true,
                            "async": true
                          }],
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                                {
                                  "corejs": false,
                                  "helpers": true,
                                  "regenerator": true,
                                  "useESModules": true
                                }
                              ],
                              "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                              "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
                              "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread",
                              "react-hot-loader/babel"]
                }
            }
        },
```

And at the and i can pick-up process from vscode debugging console, **launch.json** like below

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Node: Nodemon",
      "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
      "restart": true,
      "protocol": "inspector",
  },
```

Now it has been working with debugging and hotreloading, if there is a overlooked problem or feature please comment

Answer (score 0):

use require instead of import. this might help
for example :
write this :

```
const express =  require('express')
```

instead of:

```
import express from 'express'
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use

```
const express = require('express');
```

instead of

```
import express from 'express';
```